# VideoLibrary "GetDecryptionFunction failed"

Tags: c#, video-library

When I try to download a yt video using **VideoLibrary** I get: *GetDecryptionFunction failed*

```
        var youTube = YouTube.Default;
        var video = youTube.GetVideo(link);
        File.WriteAllBytes((video.FullName + ".mp3"), video.GetBytes());
```

Comment: Have you tried with unprotected content. Hence it is not possible to download protected content from YouTube.

Comment: I have made mp3 (no things special) downloader for unprotected content https://github.com/maythamfahmi/YouTuber?files=1